# App crashes when adding an ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

This is my xml. The imageview1 works fine, the problem comes when i add the second imageview. I did a little research and found something about the problem having to do with the @id+/ but i didnt really understood. Can someones tell what's wrong?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="@string/check"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:text="@string/mensaje"
    android:textSize="35sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/pais"
    android:textSize="35sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/canada" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
    android:src="@drawable/paloma" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post logcat of the error?

Comment: The way you use `@+id` is wrong. You should use `@+id` with + only **the first time** you use a new identifier. All other times after that you should use `@id`. `@+id` creates a new variable and you want to do it only once.

Comment: Could you expand on this? like give an example?

Comment: For example, in button2 you should use `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button3"` as you already declared `+@id/button3` above it.

Comment: That's what i thought. Still not working though

Comment: Something weird happened. Im getting this now. "The following classes could not be found: - ImageView (Change to android.widget.ImageView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)". This is displayed in my graphical layout and my ImageView Image is not showing.

Comment: I didn't say it would fix your problem, that's why I put it into comments. I just noticed you were doing it incorrectly so wanted to make you aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an end tag for your `RelativeLayout`. Just put this at the bottom:

```
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, have you made sure that the drawable that you're putting on the `ImageView` exists?

Comment: Wops, i do have it, i just didnt put it in the question. will fix now. Also, de imageview does exists

Answer (score 1):

replace the RelativeLayout with

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

there can be only one xmlns attribute there are two in your code